# different source code in c# webBrowser than in chrome

Tags: c#, html, winforms, google-chrome, webbrowser-control

I try to click hyperlink on this website https://ppuslugi.mf.gov.pl/_/

The problem is that in webBrowser form website have different source code than in chrome browser and I can't do anything.

This is example source code from chrome `<a class="SidebarLink SidebarLinkChVAT" href="javascript:;" onclick="FWDC.executeAction(1005, null, 'FLOW');" title="">Sprawdź podmiot w VAT</a>`

and this is code from webBrowser

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Portal Podatkowy</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Icon/favicon.ico?_=636674229211578551" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link rel="icon" href="../Icon/favicon.png?_=636674229211578551" type="image/png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css?h=1503528615">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/jquery.qtip.min.css?h=1233152629">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.css?h=2111090127">
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.IE.css?h=821935023">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.IE.6.css?h=1759023773">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.IE.7.css?h=-1436668032">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.IE.8.css?h=1091124831">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.IE.9.css?h=-1672926084">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/WDC.Controls.css?h=691064069">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resource/Site.css?h=-489788811">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery-1.11.0.min.js?h=-1771467163"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js?h=235038801"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/globalize.min.js?h=-688734152"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js?h=1429086502"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js?h=-488335589"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery.watermark-3.2.0.min.js?h=1554632688"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery.qtip.min.js?h=1160580903"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery-ui-1.10.4-i18n.min.js?h=1755188919"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/jquery.form.js?h=580982893"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/json2.min.js?h=-1255456783"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Resource/WDC.js?h=-1395956209"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FWDC.initialize({
standardDecodes: {"CapsLockOn":"Caps Lock jest w\u0142\u0105czony","LogPassword":"Has\u0142o dla loga:","MsgBoxOk":"OK","MsgBoxCancel":"Anuluj","MsgBoxYes":"Tak","MsgBoxNo":"Nie","DialogClose":"Zamknij","NotifyReply":"Odpowiedz","NotifyDismiss":"Zamknij","StopAutoRefresh":"Stop","LogOffPrompt":"Czy na pewno chcesz si\u0119 wylogowa\u0107? Wszelkie niezapisane zmiany zostan\u0105 utracone.","CookiesDisabled":"W Twojej przegl\u0105darce ciasteczka zosta\u0142y wy\u0142\u0105czone. Cookies s\u0105 wymagane do korzystania z tej witryny.","RestartSession":"Rozpocznij now\u0105 sesj\u0119","ReplayTitle":"Odtwarzanie","LoggedOff":"Wylogowany","SessionExpiring":"Twoja sesja wyga\u015bnie w ci\u0105gu 5 minut, je\u015bli nie klikniesz przycisk OK.","BusyNewWindow":"Otw\u00f3rz nowe okno","AttachmentError":"Wyst\u0105pi\u0142 nieznany b\u0142\u0105d przy pr\u00f3bie za\u0142adowania pliku.","ImportError":"Wyst\u0105pi\u0142 nieznany b\u0142\u0105d przy pr\u00f3bie zaimportowania pliku.","MediaPlay":"Play","MediaPause":"Pause","MediaError":"An error occurred while loading the media file.","MediaLoading":"Loading"},cssVer: '13288045'});
</script>


        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Site.css">-->
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
            <style type="text/css">
                .gradient { filter: none; }
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="PageWrapper">
            <div class="PageHeader">
                <div class="middlenav-image-box"><a class="header-link middleheader_button_kt" href="http://www.finanse.mf.gov.pl/web/wp/kontakt" title="Przejdź do danych kontaktowych" target="_blank"> <span>Kontakt</span> </a></div>
                <div class="middlenav-image-box"><a class="header-link middleheader_button_pp" href="http://www.portalpodatkowy.mf.gov.pl/" title="Przejdź do Portalu Podatkowego" target="_blank"> <span>Portal<br />Podatkowy</span> </a></div>
                <div class="middlenav-image-box"><a class="header-link middleheader_button_mf" href="http://www.mf.gov.pl/ministerstwo-finansow" title="Przejdź do serwisu BIP Ministerstwa Finansów" target="_blank"> <span>Ministerstwo<br />Finansów</span> </a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ContentWrapper">
                <noscript><div class="NoScript">Javascript must be enabled to use this site.</div></noscript><script type="text/javascript">FWDC.setVerLast('1._.dPkTWHMYZprN_WET1fEqBr4-5k41', 'HTML: _ [Page,139211310] @ 2018-07-17 11:15:24.0640')
</script><script>FWDC.loadManager();</script>
<div id="FAST_MANAGER_PLACEHOLDER"></div>

                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get to the element from chrome example in this situation?

Comment: `<script>FWDC.loadManager();</script>` loads the content of the site deferred into your `<div id="FAST_MANAGER_PLACEHOLDER"></div>`. The sources you see is the HTML you recieve from the server, not the HTML rendered at runtime. Try pressing Ctrl+U in chrome, compare that to the HTML above, you will notice its the same representation of HTML initially retrieved from the server

Comment: is it possible to get html code like in chrome in webBrowser? I can't see a lot of elements in webBrowser actually.

Comment: Yes, you need to retrieve the outerHtml property either in javascript or using the OM of the webbrowser control. Example shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-access-the-html-source-in-the-managed-html-document-object-model